# How to take a screenshot on Mac while keeping the aspect ratio of the capture area

Tags: screen-capture

I know I can open the Screenshot tool by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>.
I can drag the mouse around to specify the area I want to take a screenshot of, but I am wondering how I can keep the width and height ratio 1:1 when moving the mouse cursor.

In image editing software, the combination is usually to hold <kbd>shift</kbd> while dragging. On mac using the screenshot tool, this means to lock one of the axis depending on where you start your drag motion. It locks the width if you start dragging up or down, and locks the height if you start dragging left or right.

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> on the other hand makes the capture area grow in both direction.

holding either <kbd>cmd</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> seems to do nothing.

I really hope there is a key combination to make the width and height scale the same, but I cannot figure out which key combination to use.

**EDIT**

My version of macOS is Mojave 10.14.5.

And just to clarify, I want to keep the selection area to grow and remain at 1:1 ratio while actually moving the cursor around, similar to this:

[image]

Alternatively resizing the area in equal proportion to each other, meaning the width and the height changes so that the original aspect ratio is intact. The resulting image itself does not have to be 1:1

[image]

Comment: Just checking your actual end requirement - is it that you need the selection area to grow and remain at 1:1 ration while actually moving the cursor around, or is it more that you want to ensure you get a 1:1 ratio screenshot?

Comment: Also, advising the version of macOS you have installed may also be relevant.

Comment: I want it grow and remain at 1:1 while moving the cursor around. I am using Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: Have a look at: [How to take a screenshot on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201361) & [How to take screenshots and record your screen in macOS Mojave](https://www.imore.com/screenshot-mac)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I could not find what I was looking for, but found another neat option: `To exclude the window's shadow from the screenshot, press and hold the Option (⌥) key while you click.`

Comment: I know you would not find what you were looking for and only posted the links so you'd know what Apple had to say about the feature and I included the one from iMore because they usually provide additional information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know the exact thing you are trying to do is not natively possible in the current version of macOS Mojave. The current modifiers that do exist for the screenshot tool are as follows:

- Holding <kbd>shift</kbd>  moves only one of the sides of the capture area.
- Holding <kbd>option</kbd> scales up all sides of the capture area from the center.
- Holding <kbd>space</kbd>  allows you to move the capture area around.

Alternatively you can use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>    which will give you the onscreen capture controls with a few more options for resizing the capture area, however this doesn't include any options for locking the aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could not find any extra options with `cmd+shift+5` that can do what I want to do.

Comment: I guess "not possible" is the correct answer until it is possible.

Comment: I downloaded a few of the popular third-party screenshot apps, however none of them had the function that you are needing, so I think that is true for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't appear to be possible to do this while taking a screenshot, here's a simple process to achieve the same result quickly using the built-in Preview app:

1. Screenshot the whole screen to the clipboard with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>
2. Launch the Preview app (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up Spotlight, type `prev`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)
3. ➕ Paste the screenshot into a new Preview window with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>
4. ⬚ Select the square area of the screen you want by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging the mouse pointer to make a selection. (You can also hold <kbd>Option</kbd> to expand the selection from a centre point.)
5. Copy the contents of the selection with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Alternatively, if you want the image in a file, at the last step crop the image to the selection using <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, then save it.

---

If you're going to be doing this a lot, *you can change your screenshot defaults* to always open the image in Preview! Here's how:

1. Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to open the settings for screenshots.
2. In the **Options** menu, under **Save to**, click on **Preview**.
3. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

After doing that, screenshotting the whole screen with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> (don't need the <kbd>Control</kbd>) will do steps 1, 2, and 3 from the above, so you just need to make a selection and copy.